# PyCharm запускает скрипты в своей Python Console

Tags: python, pycharm

Раньше, когда я запускал скрипты с помощью `Ctrl + Shift + F10` или кнопкой Run, то вся программа выполнялась в окне Run, а сейчас в Python Console. Как мне вернуть старый метод запуска скриптов?

[image: Run - то, шо надо. Python Conole - то, шо не надо]

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решил. Оказалось, что каким-то образом для всех новых Python скриптов был установлен по умолчанию запуск в консоли.

Comment: а как данную проблему-то решили??)

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно нажать пкм на нужный файл сверху окошка для кода
2. Выбрать "More Run/Debug"
3. Выбрать "Modify Run Configuration..."
4. Убрать в открывшемся меню галочку "Run with Python Console"